Specify output device for multiple files in playlist
I'm running Windows 10 (10.0.19045.4170) which has the ability to forward sound from specific applications to specific audio devices (Settings -> System -> Sound -> App volume and device preferences).
I'm using SMPlayer (22.7) to play multiple files in its Playlist window (i.e. no saved playlist). However, since SMPlayer is merely a UI frontend for the command-line media player (in this case mpv), each time a new file starts the mpv process is restarted. This means the device setting gets reset for each new file in the Playlist.
It seems the device settings are tied to the window title of the process, which changes with each file.
How can I get the Windows setting of audio output device to be preserved across files in the Playlist?
